# Which geo-projection to use for odometry

Tags: odometry, geometry

I would like to make a little survey regarding the (geo)spatial projection that you use when elaborating your GPS and movement data for the spatial awareness of your robots.

Moving all GPS coordinates to a **planar projection** seems to be the more reasonable choice since not only distances (for which several [formulas and approximations](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) exist), but bearings must be computed.

Generally, although scales are pretty small here, avoiding *equirectangular approximation* seems a good idea in order to keep a more consistent system.

Avoiding working in the 3D world (Haversine and other great-circle stuff) is probably a good idea too to keep computations low-cost.

Moving the world to a 2D projection is hence what seems to be the best solution, despite reprojection of all input GPS coordinates is needed.

I would like to get opinions and ideas on the subject 
(...if ever anyone is interested in doing it U_U).

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Campa, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so **questions that ask for a list of approaches** or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on the size of the area where you want to operate your robot.

For me it was always good enough to use [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection), because for my assumptions "at most 1km large area at most 1000km from where I live" the error always comes up as negligible (I don't remember the value now and I don't have time to calculate it, but my guess would be under 1mm). You should calculate it and decide for yourself.

If your robot will operate on a significantly larger part of the Earth and would have problems with this kind of distortion, I guess that it would be worth to invest into a proper 3D world model instead of fighting with projection deformations.